# code doesnt work from unknown reason (no errors)

Tags: java

so basically im a beginner programmer and im trying to build this very simple soduku generator with a brute force algorithm but for some reason it doesn't work, what it is supposed to do is i divided to board in to 9 cubes of 9 number like in the game and the software randomly sets values between 1-9 to the 2D array that is the board one by one all while checking that the value it sets isn't appearing again in the rows its in(like the rules of the game) and i made it so it is not possible that the same number appears in the same box of 9 numbers(like in the game)

if anyone is experienced with code i would be really thankful if you helped a newbie out

CODE :

```
    // package whatever; // don't place package name!

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    class random_board
    {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
          //  while (pass = false){


                /*ArrayList<Integer[]> Random_Pick_List = new ArrayList<>();
         Random_Pick_List= [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9];*/
            int[][] board = new int[9][9];

       int calum = 0;
     for(int r =0;r<=2;r++) {    
      int line = 0;
      for (int q =0; q<=2;q++) {   
           ArrayList<Integer> Random_Pick_List =
            new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
        int counter = 9;
        for (int i = 0 ; i<=3;i++){
            for (int j = 0 ; j<=3;j=j){
                int n= floor(Math.random() * counter);

                board[j+line][i+calum]= Random_Pick_List.get(n);
                if (board[i][0] != n && board[i][1] != n&& board[i][2] != n && board[i][3] != n && board[i][4] != n && board[i][5] != n && board[i][6] != n && board[i][7] != n && board[i][8] != n && board[0][j] != n && board[1][j] != n && board[2][j] != n && board[3][j] != n && board[4][j] != n && board[5][j] != n && board[6][j] != n && board[7][j] != n && board[8][j] != n )  
                j++;
                counter--;
                Random_Pick_List.remove(n);

            }
            }
        }

      line =line +3;
      }  
     calum=calum+3;
     //}




    //pass = board_check(board);
    //}

         for (int i =0;i<=9;i++){
            for (int j =0;j<=9;j++){
                   System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

     /* for (int i =0;i<=9;i++){
            for (int j =0;j<=9;j++){
    public boolean board_check(integer[][] board ) {
        for (int i =0;i<=9;i++){
            for (int j =0;j<=9;j++){
            int n = board[i][j];
            board[i][j]=10;
     if (board[i][0] != n && board[i][1] != n&& board[i][2] != n && board[i][3] != n && board[i][4] != n && board[i][5] != n && board[i][6] != n && board[i][7] != n && board[i][8] != n && board[0][j] != n && board[1][j] != n && board[2][j] != n && board[3][j] != n && board[4][j] != n && board[5][j] != n && board[6][j] != n && board[7][j] != n && board[8][j] != n )  
        boolean pass = true;
        }
       }
    return pass;

    }
    */
    }

        private static int floor(double d) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what does this mean to you: ***for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j = j)***??

Comment: i just wanted to do a for loop that does not change on its own, when i think about it now it could have been a while loop haha